# How do I enable language button in samsung keyboard

Tags: samsung

How do I enable language button in samsung keyboard
I upgraded to android 7 in my samsung galaxy and the language switch button was gone

- I brought it back through enabling all accessibility services but i can't do that[image]
  how can i have it without enabling accessibility apps

Comment: Pressing on the globe icon (second from bottom left) should change the language.